# Mysql update first unique match only

Tags: mysql, sql-update, distinct-values, distinct-on

I have a table with multiple occurence of a value (SKU) linked with a certain value for another column (column2). I want to update the value of column2 with the first match of SKU.

Update table
set column2 = test
where sku = 18.

I have twice the value 18 for sku, but wanna update column2 only on the first occurence of sku = 18.

How

Comment: You need to define which is the first occurance of a SKU to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

```
update table set column2 = test where sku = 18 order by id limit 1;
```